# sentence order and problems with articles

Tags: género, artículos, objetos-indirectos, objetos-directos

I am having trouble with the following sentences. Obviously I'm missing something.

> No me lo puedo creer - I cannot believe it

So in the sentence above I believe "lo" is an the indirect object & believe is the direct object. Why is the "me" used? Is it purely for emphasis?

> pensar que me gustas - to think that I like you

Why is the "me" not a "yo"?

> me ayudó bastante en el trabajo - He/she helped me a lot at work

How would I know that the "me" goes at the start of the sentence in this instance? Why is the "el" needed before the trabajo?

> Dio un consejo al niño - He gave advice to the child

Should the transalation above actually be, "he gave some advice to the child"?

Comment: These are four different topics you're bringing up. When possible you should ask separate questions in cases like this.

Comment: You should've asked 4 different questions, and btw it will help if you complete your profile so at least we know your Spanish level and your native language.

Comment: @pablodf76 - I wish you wouldn't dive in and answer a badly posed question.  I know you like to help -- how about compromising and answering one of the four questions?

Comment: @aparente001 how about rather than moaning at someone trying to help that you actually make a useful contribution. If my question is badly posed (more than possible and no problems with you saying that) then maybe explain why for future reference. By suggesting he answers one section as a compromise doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: He *is* right, you know (@aparente0001 is right I mean). Questions like these should be split. I did mention that in a comment but went and answered them anyway instead of taking the time to explain, for which I'm sorry. The idea behind this is making it easier for future readers to find an answer to a specific question that has already been answered here.

Comment: @mHelpMe - Folks here will go above and beyond the call of duty to help you.  Please, help us help you.

Comment: @aparente001 I do appreciate people here are very helpful. Re-reading my earlier comment I feel I should have phrased it better, sounds harsher than intended, next time will have my morning coffee before posting :-) Anyways lesson learnt & hopefully my next question (which I'm sure is only around the corner) will be better

Comment: @mHelpMe - Sounds good.  Welcome to the site!  ¡Bienvenid@ al sitio!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's begin with the *me* questions. *Me* is the object pronoun corresponding to the first person singular (the subject pronoun is *yo*, of course). It works both as direct and indirect object (just like English *me*).

> *No me lo puedo creer.*

This is not a typical use of *me* as object pronoun. Instead the verb *creer* is used in its so-called **pronominal** form. There are a lot of optional pronominal verbs in Spanish where you won't find much difference between the two forms, like for example *caer* and *caerse*. In this case, *No lo puedo creer* is also correct.

> *pensar que me gustas*

How to use the verb *gustar* is a topic in itself. It just works like that. *Gustar* doesn't mean "to like", it means "to please". Basically what in English you would use as the subject you must place here in the object position and vice versa. There are not many verbs like these in Spanish. *Faltar* is another (*me falta algo* = "I am missing something", lit. "to me is lacking something").

> *me ayudó bastante en el trabajo*

There are rules as to where the clitic pronouns go in the sentence. In general they go before the main conjugated verbs, as in this case, and after the infinitives and gerunds. This is another full topic in itself.

You need *el* before *trabajo* because that's how things work in Spanish; definite articles are used much more often than in English. Note that in English you say "at work", "at home", "at school", etc., but these are all fixed phrases or idioms. Even in English you'll say "at the office", "at the door", etc. In Spanish these fixed phrases where you can omit the article are just fewer. Also, *en el trabajo* can both mean "at work" or "with the work [I was doing]".

> *Dio un consejo al niño.*

The most correct traslation of this would be "S/he gave the child a piece of advice." Unlike "advice", in Spanish *consejo* is a countable noun, so you say *un consejo, dos consejos, tres consejos; el consejo, los consejos*. For practical purposes, however, you can simply translate *consejo* as uncountable, unless the example somehow emphasizes that it was only one specific piece of advice.

Comment: Additionally I would add that "Give Advice" can be translated to the verb in Spanish "Aconsejar", or the translation can also be 

"  he gave an advice to the child "

Answer (score 1):

> No me lo puedo creer - I cannot believe it

EDIT: I'm not sure about the indirect object, but you're probably right.

"creerse algo" means indeed the same as "creer algo" with emphasis. But it's extremely common and I've never heard or read "No lo puedo creer". (I'm Spanish)

> pensar que me gustas - to think that I like you

This verb is just used the other way around in Spanish; you don't like things, things "like" you. The subject is omitted, think about "Ellos me gusta**n**".

> me ayudó bastante en el trabajo - He/she helped me a lot at work

The subject is omitted again, this is very common and I understand that can be a problem. Think about "Ella me ayudó". About the article: I'm sorry, that's idiomatic; and it can refer to a certain job as well as "at work".

> Dio un consejo al niño - He gave advice to the child

Here I can agree with you, I don't think it can be exact because
"consejo" can be countable in Spanish :). Think "he gave a piece of advice". It can also be used as in English, though ("Dio consejo").